# Как делаются команды с опциями? Python Telegram бот

Tags: python, telebot

Пример:
/check (Текст)
(Текст) должно записываться в переменную

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам поможет `split()`:

Отправим боту: `/check 1 2 3`

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['check'])
def check(message):
    print(message.text.split())

>>> ['/check', '1', '2', '3']

    print(message.text.split()[1])  # [0] будет выводить /check
    print(message.text.split()[2])
    print(message.text.split()[3])

>>> 1
    2
    3
```

только не забывайте обрабатывать `len()` и `delimiter`

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Такого прям синтаксиса или готовых методов библиотеки нет. Вы видите команду в пакете пришедшем от Телеграм, и дальше просто производите парсинг всей оставшейся строки. Только вручную. Так как прям синтаксиса команды с параметрами в самом Телеграме не зафиксировано ни какого. Можно так:

```
/command1567
```

в этом лучае нужно будет парсить само тело команды что бы выделить из него параметр 1567

можно так:

```
/command 1567
```

в этом случае нужно будет парсить оставшуюся строчку после команды

а можно придумать и свои варианты типа:

```
/command param=value
```

тогда парсинг команды будет в разы проще, но как единая ссылка работать эта команда не сможет, а значит её и второй мной указанный вариант будет сложней использовать пользователю вашего бота